# jQuery cannot find elements unless I put a timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

For some reason when I try and select an element from the page it only works if I put a timeout of 0 milliseconds. If I don't put the timeout it just returns what is there before the Ionic framework has been loaded. Any ideas? Below is my code.

The order of loading is jQuery, Ionic, Custom Script (as seen below).

**Working**

```
ionic.DomUtil.ready(function(){

    setTimeout(function(){console.log($('body').html())},0);

});
```

**Not Working**

```
ionic.DomUtil.ready(function(){

    console.log($('body').html());

});
```

***EDIT:*** Obviously I could just put a timeout on everything I want to do but that's bad practice so would be nice to know the underlying cause!

***EDIT (2):*** I have managed to get it do show the HTML doing the following... However, it is not ideal...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    console.log($(this).find('body')[0]);

});
```

It's almost as if some jQuery functions are not working even though the $ is being initiated otherwise it return $ is undefined.

Comment: It looks like your `ready` function is called before any modifications are made to body. Try `ionic.Platform.ready`

Comment: @Cheery I did try that too but still does exactly the same thing.

Comment: ionic.DomUtil.ready is correct one. I would recommand to add Custom Scripts before closing body tag(at the end of the layout)

Comment: I normally do when I'm building normal web apps but didn't in Ionic. And I just tried putting my custom scripts at the end before the </body> closing tag and it still does exactly the same thing!

Comment: Use external JavaScript and put your Library `<script>` tags before your own external JavaScript `<script>` tags.

Comment: Yep I have done this already...

Comment: can you skim this?  [preventing conflicts btwn jquery and other libraries](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/)...?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know ionic, but you tried with jquery stand alone? like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  console.log($('body'));

});
```

Maybe there are other way to do the same with ionic

Comment: Yep I have tried this too and only works if it has a timeout of 0 or more.

Comment: ok, so, may you change body dynamically? are there content by default on your html?

Comment: Ionic framework handles all of this itself. It is a mobile framework using AngularJS. It has a function called ionic.platform.ready and ionic.domutil.ready which should only fire when the device and/or platform is ready.

Comment: ok, maybe is a problem with angular, the bootstrap of the angular app, when you use ng-app you use automatic (or imperative) bootstrap, in some cases you need do it the manual way like this:
`
    angular.element(document).ready(function() {
      angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
    });
`
more info: https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.26/docs/guide/bootstrap

Can you try it?